# Why is the Clinton Global Initiative being closed?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, hillary-clinton, clinton-foundation

I noticed [this article](http://observer.com/2017/01/the-clinton-foundation-shuts-down-clinton-global-initiative/) recently, which seems to tie the closure of the Clinton Global Initiative to Hillary Clinton's loss in the election.

However, the closure was actually announced [back in September](https://www.bloomberg.com/politics/articles/2016-09-19/clinton-global-initiative-ends-run-with-some-of-shine-worn-off), before the election results were known.

If the closure of CGI wasn't caused by the electoral loss, why is it closing?  Specifically, what reason did the CGI give for closing? Did they provide any explanation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/post-politics/wp/2016/09/21/bill-clinton-forcefully-defends-his-foundation-at-the-final-clinton-global-initiative-meeting/?utm_term=.5088462ce36d), the Clintons planned to discontinue the Clinton Global Initiative regardless of how the election turned out.

This makes sense. If Hillary won, as the Clintons expected, even they would understand the problem of maintaining the CGI while she served as president. If Hillary lost, contributions would likely dry up.

Apparently, [they have](http://www.powerlineblog.com/archives/2017/01/tough-times-at-the-clinton-foundation.php) — a trend that [predates](http://www.dailywire.com/news/10968/how-much-have-clinton-foundation-donations-dropped-hank-berrien) the election.